# Why can't I remove the NSUserDefaults key in swift?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

When I run the following test case, the testRemovePref method fails as it doesn't actually remove the value. I'm using Xcode 7.2. Why is this happening?

EDIT: This is only occurring when the tests belong to a Framework Library. The tests below seem to work fine when run in an Application. Odd.

```
import XCTest
class NSUserDefaultsTests: XCTestCase {
    func testSetPref() {
        let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        prefs.setValue("value1", forKeyPath: "testKey")
        let val : String? = prefs.stringForKey("testKey")
        print("value=\(val)") // prints "value1"
        XCTAssertEqual("value1", val)

    }

    func testRemovePref() {
        let prefs = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        prefs.removeObjectForKey("testKey")

        let val : String? = prefs.stringForKey("testKey")
        print("value=\(val)") // prints "value1"
        XCTAssertNil(val)
    }
}
```

Comment: that's strange, I ran your tests and they all passed.

Comment: Where are you calling them? Is there a chance that your calling `testSetPref` twice?

Comment: Your tests should not depend on the side effects of other tests. As far as I know, XCTest does not guarantee your tests will be run in the order you write them.

Comment: Interesting, @ahmedOnawale - I created a new APPLICATION project and they work fine. However, when I create a new Framework Library they do not.

Comment: I'm just running them from the test runner.

This is just a reproducible example, but in my real tests/app a test can't reset/remove values that were left over from another test. Even the setUp() method doesn't seem to have access to them.

As I updated the description with an EDIT, this only occurs for a Framework Library which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

> This is only occurring when the tests belong to a Framework Library.
>   The tests below seem to work fine when run in an Application.

An application automatically synchronizes defaults when you send it to the background. This doesn't happen with tests. Try adding:

```
prefs.synchronize()
```

Comment: I've tried that (as well as a nice sleep() to wait for it to hopefully synchronize), but according to other posts, I understand that synchronize() is no longer recommended. Plus, wondering why does it work fine in my application tests, just not framework tests?